# Bash copy command not working after file rename

Tags: filenames, rm, cp, mv

I have this installer shell script in a bash script.

1. I am doing a rename of the existing text file (backing it up).
2. I remove old file
3. Copy fresh file to the target dir

   ```
   mv /target/data.ini /target/data_$(date +"%Y%m%d_%H%M%S").ini       
   rm -f /target/data.ini     
   cp /install/data.ini /target/data.ini
   ```

For some reason the cp command does not always copy the file.
Is it possible that previous mv or rm  operation was not completed?

I am unable to see any error since its running as part of the script; if I execute the commands manually it's working fine.

Comment: What does "not always working" mean? Does the file not copy? Does it give an error? Does it end up as the date-stamped version?

Comment: file is not being copied....

Comment: Is `/target` an automounted filesystem?

Comment: I am not sure, how to check?

Comment: Scripts still output errors. E.g., by default scripts run from cron will email their errors. The `logger` command is very useful to send script output (including errors) to the system log or journal. Capturing the error messages would make it *much* easier to debug the issue. I would suggest getting the error message logged or emailed as much easier than taking random guesses at what might be going wrong.

Comment: That is `/install/data.ini` it seems un-related to the `mv`? Also what do you mean backup (`mv` does not do any thing like a backup).

Comment: What are the error messages?

Comment: i added -v to the cp and i don't see any error message.  i see correct path, i forgot to add step number 2 (rm -f) i am not sure if this is the issue

Comment: The `rm` should not be needed, since after `mv`, there will no longer be a file named /target/data.ini. Do you have the `-e` option (exit on error) set in this script? If so, the `rm` will get a "No such file or directory" error, and that'll exit the script.

Comment: @GordonDavisson, `rm /target/data.ini` would indeed exit with an error, but `rm -f` [ignores nonexisting files without complaints](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/rm.html): "**-f** Do not prompt for confirmation. Do not write diagnostic messages or modify the exit status in the case of no file operands, or in the case of operands that do not exist."

Comment: Try adding `sleep 2 ;` before `cp` command. It may slow down but can increase precision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I execute the commands manually it's working fine.

There is a clue. It could be a path problem. When I write something, especially for a script, I always like to include the path to the command.

```
$ which date
/usr/bin/date
```

Then, I would add error checking in the script:

```
if [ -f /target/data.ini ]
then
  # Note spaces separating the parenthesis from the command
  /bin/mv /target/data.ini /target/data_$( /usr/bin/date +"%Y%m%d_%H%M%S" ).ini
  if [ $? -ne 0 ]
  then
     echo "Error on MV command"
     exit
  fi
  else
    echo "Error: Can't find /target/data.ini"
    exit
  fi
  cp /install/data.ini /target/data.ini  
  #Same type of error checking here
```

That ought to fix or shed some light on your error.